# Ember dynamic route with nested route inside it

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am kind of new to ember .. and i am having a little problem

the problem is that i want to generate a route with an id and another

nested route inside it for example "doctors/visit/(the visit id)/order

here is my router file

```
this.route('doctor', function() {
    this.route('visit', {path:'/visit/:visit_id'});
});
```

my visit file

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params){
    return this.store.findRecord('visit',params.visit_id);
  }
});
```

how can i reference one level new route to make it like the one i wrote in the example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e150fb8a9094379d8146feb261b6def0?openFiles=routes.doctor.visit.order.js%2C&route=%2Fdoctor%2Fvisit%2F1%2Forder) I have prepared for you. You can define nested routes as seen in `router.js` and you can specify corresponding routes within sub-folders. If you also want to define nested routes with multiple dynamic segments you can see the official [guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/defining-your-routes/)'s "Dynamic Segments" part.

Answer (score 3):

```
this.route('doctor', function() {
  this.route('visit', {
    path: '/visit/:visit_id'
   }, function() {
    this.route('order');
  });
});
```

You need something like this, or order also needs dynamic param?